# bnd-export-maven-plugin questions

Tags: maven, osgi, bnd, bndtools

I am using bnd-export-maven-plugin to generate a runnable jar, with the pom.xml defined as follows:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>test</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${bnd-maven-plugin-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-bnd-process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>bnd-export-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${bnd-maven-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnChanges>false</failOnChanges>
                <bndruns>
                    <bndrun>com.xyz.masterdata.application.services.bndrun</bndrun>
                </bndruns>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>export</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.annotation</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.service.jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-maven-plugin-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.ws.rs-api-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet-api-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.foundation</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xyz.foundation.common.provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.foundation</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xyz.foundation.common.provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.foundation</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xyz.foundation.web.rest.provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.masterdata.party</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xyz.masterdata.party.logic.provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.masterdata.party</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xyz.masterdata.party.rest.provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My bndrun file is given here:

```
-runfw: org.eclipse.osgi;version=3.13
-runee: JavaSE-1.8
-runprovidedcapabilities: ${native_capability}

-resolve.effective: active

-runproperties: \
    osgi.console=,\
    org.osgi.service.http.port=9001,\
    osgi.console.enable.builtin=false

-runrequires: \
    osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.shell)',\
        osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.command)',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.mysql.jdbc',\
    bnd.identity;id='org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.mysql',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-base',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.xyz.foundation.common.provider',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.xyz.foundation.web.rest.api',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.xyz.foundation.web.rest.provider',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.xyz.masterdata.party.logic.provider',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.xyz.masterdata.party.rest.provider',\
        osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=com.xyz.masterdata.application.services)'
-runbundles: \
    ch.qos.logback.classic;version='[1.2.3,1.2.4)',\
    ch.qos.logback.core;version='[1.2.3,1.2.4)',\
    com.xyz.masterdata.application.services;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)',\
        com.fourthiq.masterdata.party.logic.provider;version='[0.0.0,0.0.1)',\
    com.mysql.jdbc;version='[5.1.46,5.1.47)',\
    org.apache.aries.jpa.javax.persistence_2.1;version='[2.7.0,2.7.1)',\
    org.apache.felix.configadmin;version='[1.9.8,1.9.9)',\
    org.apache.felix.configurator;version='[1.0.6,1.0.7)',\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.command;version='[1.0.2,1.0.3)',\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime;version='[1.0.10,1.0.11)',\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.shell;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)',\
    org.apache.felix.scr;version='[2.1.10,2.1.11)',\
    org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.mysql;version='[1.3.5,1.3.6)',\
    org.osgi.service.transaction.control;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)',\
    slf4j.api;version='[1.7.25,1.7.26)',\
    tx-control-provider-jdbc-xa;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)',\
    tx-control-service-xa;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)',\
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations;version='[2.9.8,2.9.9)',\
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core;version='[2.9.8,2.9.9)',\
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind;version='[2.9.8,2.9.9)',\
    com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-base;version='[2.9.8,2.9.9)',\
    com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider;version='[2.9.8,2.9.9)',\
    com.xyz.foundation.common.provider;version='[0.0.0,0.0.1)',\
    com.xyz.foundation.web.rest.api;version='[0.0.0,0.0.1)',\
    com.xyz.foundation.web.rest.provider;version='[0.0.0,0.0.1)',\
    org.apache.aries.javax.jax.rs-api;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)',\
    com.xyz.masterdata.party.rest.provider;version='[0.0.0,0.0.1)',\
    io.swagger.core.v3.swagger-annotations;version='[2.0.7,2.0.8)',\
    org.apache.aries.jax.rs.whiteboard;version='[1.0.1,1.0.2)',\
    org.apache.felix.http.jetty;version='[4.0.6,4.0.7)',\
    org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api;version='[1.1.2,1.1.3)',\
    org.apache.servicemix.specs.annotation-api-1.3;version='[1.3.0,1.3.1)',\
    org.osgi.service.jaxrs;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)',\
    org.osgi.util.function;version='[1.1.0,1.1.1)',\
    org.osgi.util.promise;version='[1.1.0,1.1.1)',\
    tx-control-provider-jpa-xa;version='[1.0.0,1.0.1)'
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when launching the application:

```
randy@MacBook-Pro target % java -jar com.xyz.masterdata.application.services.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/ServiceListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at aQute.launcher.pre.EmbeddedLauncher.executeWithRunPath(EmbeddedLauncher.java:145)
    at aQute.launcher.pre.EmbeddedLauncher.findAndExecute(EmbeddedLauncher.java:106)
    at aQute.launcher.pre.EmbeddedLauncher.main(EmbeddedLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.ServiceListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 14 more
```

Note that I may use the referenced .bndrun file to launch the application just fine from within Eclipse, and the application is generated just fine when using gradle.

The maven command I used to build this runnable jar file is simply as follows:

```
mvn clean package
```

I have further extracted the content of the runnable jar file, with the following showing embedded jar files.

[image]

So it is clear the required jar files are not making it into the runnable jar file.  But it is unclear to me why this is.

I am making the transition from gradle to maven, however, and seem to be stuck on this last item.  Pointers for resolving are appreciated.

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: Which version of the bnd maven plugins do you use?

Comment: I am using v4.3.1.  Note the groupId is biz.aQute.bnd, not org.apache.felix.  On this latter point, not sure which is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a dependency to the felix framework. Not sure why it then works in bndtools though.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I think the problem is that you specify "-runfw: org.eclipse.osgi;version=3.13" which selects the equinox framework. You should use bndtools view to switch to the felix framework.

Maybe it works in eclipse as eclipse runs on equinox .. not sure.

Comment: I've added the felix.framework dependency to my pom.xml, but with the error persisting.  I've also updated the original post with  both pom.xml dependencies and entire .bndrun file.  Thanks for your feedback, appreciated.

Comment: I have also added to my original post, a screen shot of the extracted content of the runnable jar file.  It seems none of my dependencies are making into the jar directory... which is ultimately the issue.  So I must be missing some definition from my pom.xml file's build instructions.  Just not sure what that would be.

Comment: You can have a look at my osgi best practices repo. Maybe you are missing an index definition. https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-best-practices/blob/bb5eb491cdefb0817a12c630bb51d03fd8666b4c/app/pom.xml#L206 . Btw you also have to refer to the index in the bndrun.